# 16.10 Live USB boots into tty1 and then shuts down

Tags: boot, live-usb, 16.10

I was working off of a Yakety live USB when I got a black screen with white text at the top saying something about "loop"malfunctioning and that it was deleting what was malfunctioning. After this it shut down.

When I booted back up the entire boot went normally except usually it loads tty1and then after a few seconds loads the GUI in tty7 like normal. This time it loaded tty1 then gave me a black screen, and then shut down. It's being doing this every time I boot since.

It's worth noting that when it shuts down it's not as if the laptop shutdown at a hardware level, but it goes through the full shutdown procedure with the Ubuntu logo and everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that something corrupted the live image on the USB drive, or the USB drive itself has gone bad. Try with a fresh image on a new USB drive. If it still doesn't work, then you've very likely got a hardware malfunction, because the live image should be the same every time it boots.

Comment: Yeah I just reinstalled